# D365 Plugin error 0x80040265 when sending an email

Tags: c#, plugins, dynamics-365

I am trying to get my plugin to work, and get an exception which I am not sure how to solve.
The plugin has to send an email when the status of a Case (incident) changes.

I placed traces to multiple points in the code and figuered out that the exception happens right at the end where I try to send the e-mail using the OrganizationService's Execute function.

Here is what I get from tracing:

```
Message Block

Get Guids
InstanciateTemplateRequest
Create email
Create email in D365
emailId: cd4204d0-a32d-ec11-b6e5-000d3add9e9a
Send email

Exception Details-Details of the exception.
System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault]: An error occurred in CasePostUpdate Plugin. (Fault Detail is equal to Exception details:
ErrorCode: 0x80040265
Message: An error occurred in CasePostUpdate Plugin.
TimeStamp: 2021-10-15T10:36:57.6376945Z
OriginalException: PluginExecution
ExceptionSource: PluginExecution
--
).
```

Here is my plugin code:

```
using Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Messages;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Crm.Plugins
{
    public class CasePostUpdate : IPlugin
    {
        public void Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            // Obtain the tracing service
            ITracingService tracingService = (ITracingService)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(ITracingService));

            // Obtain the execution context from the service provider.  
            IPluginExecutionContext context = (IPluginExecutionContext)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IPluginExecutionContext));

            // The InputParameters collection contains all the data passed in the message request.  
            if (context.InputParameters.Contains("Target") && context.InputParameters["Target"] is Entity)
            {
                // Obtain the target entity from the input parameters.  
                Incident target = ((Entity)context.InputParameters["Target"]).ToEntity<Incident>();

                Incident postImage = ((Entity)context.PostEntityImages["PostImage"]).ToEntity<Incident>();

                // Obtain the organization service reference which you will need for  
                // web service calls.  
                IOrganizationServiceFactory serviceFactory = (IOrganizationServiceFactory)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IOrganizationServiceFactory));
                IOrganizationService service = serviceFactory.CreateOrganizationService(context.UserId);

                CrmServiceContext crmServiceContex = new CrmServiceContext(service);

                try
                {
                    if (context.MessageName.ToLower() != "update")
                    {
                        return;
                    }

                    tracingService.Trace("Get Guids");

                    Guid TemplateId = (from x in crmServiceContex.TemplateSet
                                        where x.Title == "Case Status Change"
                                        select x.Id)
                                        .FirstOrDefault();

                    Guid SenderQueueId = (from x in crmServiceContex.QueueSet
                                          where x.Name == "No-Reply-TrainingD365"
                                          select x.Id)
                                        .FirstOrDefault();

                    tracingService.Trace("InstanciateTemplateRequest");

                    // creates and execute request to create email instance from email template
                    InstantiateTemplateRequest instTemplateReq = new InstantiateTemplateRequest
                    {
                        TemplateId = TemplateId,
                        ObjectId = target.Id,
                        ObjectType = "incident",
                    };

                    InstantiateTemplateResponse instTemplateResp = (InstantiateTemplateResponse)service.Execute(instTemplateReq);

                    tracingService.Trace("Create email");

                    // response from above request is entity collection therefore use below syntas to access Email instance
                    Email email = instTemplateResp.EntityCollection.Entities.FirstOrDefault().ToEntity<Email>();

                    email.DirectionCode = true;
                    email.From = new List<Entity> { new Entity() { ["partyid"] = (new EntityReference("queue", SenderQueueId)), LogicalName = "activityparty" } };
                    email.To = new List<Entity> { new Entity() { ["partyid"] = postImage.OwnerId, LogicalName = "activityparty" } };
                    email.RegardingObjectId = new EntityReference("incident", postImage.Id);

                    tracingService.Trace("Create email in D365");

                    // create email into D365
                    Guid emailId = service.Create(email);

                    tracingService.Trace("emailId: " + emailId.ToString());

                    // define and execute request to submit email for delivery
                    SendEmailRequest request = new SendEmailRequest
                    {
                        EmailId = emailId,
                        TrackingToken = string.Empty,
                        IssueSend = true,
                    };

                    tracingService.Trace("Send email");

                    SendEmailResponse response = (SendEmailResponse)service.Execute(request);

                    tracingService.Trace(response.ToString());
                }

                catch (FaultException<OrganizationServiceFault> ex)
                {
                    throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException("An error occurred in CasePostUpdate Plugin.", ex);
                }

                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    tracingService.Trace("CasePostUpdate: {0}", ex.ToString());
                    throw;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This can have a multitude of causes. For effective debugging you need two types of data: the exception details (message, exception type and stacktrace, including inner exceptions) and contextual information: plugin stage/mode etc. and preferrably the input parameters, entity images etc. Details can be written to `ITracingService` using JSON-serialization.